# Implementing Measure tool with Mapbox.js

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I need help implementing leaflet.js measuring tool with my Mapox.js map. Apparently this tool is not tested with mapbox yet.
The problem I face is referencing leaflet.js to employ the measuring tool causes Mapbox.js reference to not work.
Can someone please offer some help in implementing this in my mapbox.js app?

My mapbox code:

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v1.6.1/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

Measure tool code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/taylorpeterh/lib/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/taylorpeterh/lib/leaflet-0.6.4/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/taylorpeterh/lib/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/taylorpeterh/src/L.MeasuringTool.js"></script>
```

Error received: L.mapbox missing

any help appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to provide a complete code example for this question to be answerable.

Comment: post has been edited thanks

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox.js includes Leaflet, but you're including Leaflet again on your page, overwriting Mapbox.js. The answer is to not include Leaflet again.